# Let $G$ be finite & nonsimple such that all normal subgroups of $G$ are $p$-groups for a given prime $p$. Is it true that $G$ is also a $p$-group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory, p-groups

Let $G$ be a finite non-simple group such that all normal subgroups of $G$ are $p$-groups for a given prime $p$. Suppose also that the $p$-Sylow subgroups of $G$ are not normal. Is it true that $G$ is also a $p$-group? $G$ must not be a $p$-group if its $p$-Sylow subgroup is not normal. I am more curious if such a non-$p$-group exists. (See end of question)

So far, I have noticed that the intersection of all $p$-Sylow subgroups of $G$ is the largest normal $p$-subgroup of $G$. Hence, we know that this intersection is non-trivial. Further, I'm actually only interested in centreless groups but I can't draw any connection with $p$-groups from this other than the fact that this means that each $p$-Sylow subgroup is contained in the centralizer of some element of $g \in G$.

My updated question is does a group $G$ exist with the following properties. $G$ is non-simple, centre-less, non-$p$-group such that every normal subgroup of $N \leq G$ has order $|N|=p^k$ for $1\leq k \lneq n$ where $p^n$ is order of the Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Every (non-trivial)  normal subgroup of $S_3$ is a $3-$group.  Of course, if you include $G$ as a normal subgroup of itself, then the problem is trivial.

Comment: What did you try, exactly?

Comment: Thanks @lulu, what if we make the stipulation that $G$ cannot have a normal $p$-Sylow subgroup?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Don't rush to modify your question every time someone produces a counterexample.

Comment: Hint: more or less, the answer to any variation on this question is going to be 'no'.

Comment: That's what I was thinking as well David. Could you explain why you believe this?

Comment: The answer to your last question is no, as witnessed by $S_3 \times S_2 \times S_2$.

Comment: Here is another very simple example. Let $F$ be a field of four elements, let $V$ be a two-dimensional vector space over $F$. In the semidirect product $G=V\rtimes SL(V)\cong V\rtimes A_5$ each proper normal subgroup is a $2$-group but the Sylow $2$-subgroup is not normal.

Comment: $G$ cannot be a $p$-group if you specify that the Sylow subgroups are not normal: $G$ would be its own $p$-Sylow, and is of course normal in itself. Your. desired conclusion contradicts your hypotheses.

Comment: That's a very good point Arturo. I have updated the question since I'm curious if such a non-$p$-group exists whose $p$-Sylow subgroup is not normal but which has all other normal subgroups as $p$-groups.

Comment: @Suoria I believe this because I know some finite group theory and you cannot say much about $G$ from its normal subgroup structure. Your group has a normal subgroup $N$, the product of all normal $p$-subgroups, normally denoted $O_p(G)$, and $G/N$ is a simple group. There are lots of ways for simple groups to act on $p$-groups.